# How do I make the UV islands of a single object equally?

Tags: modifiers, uv

After modelling my object, I mirrored it to the x-axis and join them with Boolean modifier ( union) into 1 object and clean up where I joined them. After that, I marked seams similarly to each side. However, the UV islands look completely different, even to the parts that are exactly the same as the object I mirrored

[image: My object, the middle part is where I joined them together]

[image: The UV islands]

The two vertical UV islands are supposed to be the same ( they are the spines of the object), as well as the flaps. I marked a middle seam where I joined the objects. I don't know if the Boolean modifier may have been the source of the problem.

Comment: I assume you mirrored it by duplicating with SHIFT + D and then S + Y -1 around the 3D cursor? Any particular reason why you didn't use, and then apply a mirror modifier? that wat you'd have ended up with a single object and wouldn't need to use a Boolean modifier at all.

Comment: @JohnEason You are right. I "Shift D" the object because I don't know how to duplicate it with the mirror modifier at the exact point like in the picture. So I copied the object, select-align objects then Boolean.

Comment: Ok I think it would be easiest if you could upload your blend file to https://pasteall.org/blend/ and include the link in a comment and I'll rustle up an answer with images showing how I'd do the mirroring. May be later this evening (Uk time) because I'm about to have a meal.

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/b88f0283ba9740d98ba9f4e7e25ac25b Thank you so much for the support. After reading your comment, I did more research on the mirror modifier and used it to mirror and clip instead of duplicate. However, the issue still occurs and I figured it might have been because the mirror modifier flip the way UV unwrap

Comment: In object mode, look at the scale of that object! Select it and CTRL - A > Scale to reset it. Then go back into Edit mode, select all and Unwrap it again. Does that look better?

Comment: Wow. That was awesome! Thank you so much.  It works, but could you explain to me how that works?

Comment: I usually reckon that if something looks off (particularly with bevelling, but it can apply to lots of other things), it's worth checking and applying the scale. Have a read of [this](https://artisticrender.com/how-and-why-do-we-apply-scale-in-blender/) article which explains it quite well. Anyhow I'm glad you're sorted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UV islands after using mirror modifier instead of Boolean as suggested in comments
[image]

Showing scale of object

[image]

Scale reset using <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and object unwrapped again with <kbd>U</kbd> > <kbd>Unwrap</kbd>.

[image]